# how to declare an array in $_SESSION?

Tags: php

I want to declare an array in `$_SESSION` to store items in a cart, so that each time a user presses the add to cart button that item is added to the array.

i tried

```
array_push($_SESSION['cart_items'],$_SESSION[product_id]);
```

but it gives me this error

```
Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in
```

Comment: What does `print_r($_SESSION['cart_items']);` gives you?

Comment: The error explains it all.  `$_SESSION['cart_items']` is not an array.  It's a string.

Comment: why didn't you just initialize `$_SESSION['cart_items'] = array()` in the first place

Comment: @Anonymous so how to solve that problem?

Comment: @user3697664 you instantiate it as an array..

Comment: @user3697664 You can look at kevinabelita's comment or Janaka's answer.

Comment: @kevinabelita i actually thought of that, but its going to initialize a new array each time so the data will be lost!

Comment: just put a simple condition above: `if(!isset($_SESSION['cart_items'])) { $_SESSION['cart_items'] = array(); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_SESSION['cart_items']` should be an array.

before you use `array_push()`, make it an array:

```
if(!is_array($_SESSION['cart_items'])){ $_SESSION['cart_items'] = array(); }
```

Then use:

```
array_push($_SESSION['cart_items'], $_SESSION['product_id']);
```

Comment: but it will remove the data because the array will be initialized each time, right?

Comment: you welcome, but if some answer fixed your problem, keep a habit to mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @user3697664 No. it only assigns an empty array if its not set already.